# Reading BJT Transistor Datasheets. Two different values for collector emitter voltage?

Tags: bjt, datasheet, npn

I've been trying to read up on BJT transistors to figure out how I can use one for a simple switching application. In order to calculate the resistances I need, I need to figure out V<sub>CE</sub>, the collector emitter saturation voltage and V<sub>BE</sub>, the base emitter voltages. But I'm noticing some of these data sheets seem to have conflicting data the way I am interpreting them.

For example, in this [P2N2222A](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF) NPN transistor, I can look in the "ON CHARACTERISTICS" table and see that V<sub>CE</sub> has a max of .3V for I<sub>B</sub>=15mA and I<sub>C</sub>=150mA.

However, in Figure 4 there is a graph of I<sub>B</sub> vs V<sub>CE</sub>. If I look at the plot for I<sub>C</sub>=150mA, and then go to I<sub>B</sub>=15mA, I see V<sub>CE</sub>=.1V and not .3V.
[image: Collector Emitter Voltage Graph]

Is the datasheet just telling me that at a maximum, the graph will be shifted up so that the value is .3V at I<sub>B</sub>=15mA? And if so should I expect the general shape of the graph to still hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the difference between *guaranteed maximum* and *typical*.  Typical specs are mostly marketing BS.  What you need to design to are the min/max specs.

The curves show typical values, so you can't rely on them.  Their point is to give you some idea how the part behaves, even if you have to use different numbers to determine part values in your design.  Think of the curves as kindof interesting, but not much more.